# Does $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (n\ln n)^{-1}$ diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

Is $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (n\ln n)^{-1}=\infty$ ?

This seems like elementary calculus, but I can't figure this out.  Can anyone supply a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint.**
$$\sum_{n=2^N}^{2^{N+1}-1} \frac{1}{n\ln n}\ge\frac{2^N}{(N+1)2^{N+1}}=\frac{1}{2(N+1)}$$

Comment: For discussion, please see the [Cauchy Condensation Test.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

Comment: Cauchy condensation test shows that the series diverges.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

HINT: Use the integral test: what happens to

$$\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{x\ln x}\;?$$

Comment: Having trouble evaluating this elementary-looking integral myself, though Mathematica says it diverges...

Comment: With the substitution $u=\ln x, du=\frac{dx}{x}$, the integral becomes $\int_{\ln 2}^\infty \frac{du}{u}$.

Comment: Ahhhh...  that's easy.  I was trying to do integration by parts...  :)

Answer (score 3):

[Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) should work.